# Search and output string from a file to xml

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

```
Received timestamp=1459434658969:
ABC: Field id=0 double 11.4
DEF: Field id=1 string >def<
GHI: Field id=2 string >g_hi<
```

I would like to read a file that contains input in the above format and would like to output the following data into an xml file:

```
ABC: 11.4
DEF: def
GHI: g_hi
```

Comment: Is there a pattern in the input file? For example, is it always the time stamp in the first row and than always the fields (separated by a space) 1 and 5 in the following rows you want to get?

Comment: yes the format is always as displayed in the question starting with the timestamp

Comment: That's not an XML File.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `grep`, `awk` and `sed` for this. First, filter out the not wanted first line containing the word `received` (you should use here unique expressions to make sure that only this line is filtered), that let `awk` split the following lines by  and than remove the `<` and `>` with `sed`:

```
cat a.txt  | grep -v received | awk '{print $1 " " $5}' | sed -e 's/[<>]//g'
```

In the above example `a.txt` contains the input

```
received timestamp=1459434658969:
ABC: Field id=0 double 11.4
DEF: Field id=1 string >def<
GHI: Field id=2 string >g_hi<
```

The result is:

```
ABC: 11.4
DEF: def
GHI: g_hi
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to pipe `grep`,`awk` ans `sed`

```
perl -e 'while (<>) {
  s/[<>]//g ;
  next if ( /received/ ) ;
  @Fld = split(" ", $_);
  printf "%s %s\n",$Fld[0],$Fld[4] ;}' a.txt
```

will do it.

you can put code in a perl file

```
perl -f a.pl  a.txt
```